# How to know if Kubernetes job is done?

Tags: kubernetes

I use Python kubernetes-client, and want to wait if the job is done:

```py
api_instance.create_namespaced_job("default", body, pretty=True)
```

This call just makes a submit job, it will return the response even though the job is still running. How can I wait for the job to finish?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. You can recognize the job is complete by watching the jobs and observing the events:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config, watch

config.load_kube_config()
api_client = client.BatchV1Api()
print("INFO:    Waiting for event to come up...")
w = watch.Watch()
for event in w.stream(api_client.list_job_for_all_namespaces):
    o = event['object']
    print(o)
    if (o.status.... = "Complete"): ....
```

Comment: Should be `if o.status.succeeded` or `if o.status.failed` or `if o.status.active`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to do this is calling in the loop:

```py
api_instance.read_namespaced_job_status()
```

...and check the result status.

You can reach the same by calling `kubectl wait` but it's not python. You can clone kubectl sources (in Go) and find how the hell they do it there.

Comment: You don't have to present 2 separate answers for your solution. Put them in a single post.

Comment: Hi @smrt28, I think your solution is right, but when I run job_status = api_instance.read_namespaced_job_status(name=name, namespace="default") then I got the error cannot get jobs.batch/status in the namespace \"default\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"name":"data-analysis-test","group":"batch","kind":"jobs"},"code":403}. I guess this is kubernetes related issue, not the python code

Comment: It's an authentication problem. Have you initialized the kubernetes client class by proper credentials?

Comment: yes, I can call other commands, as list all pods, but this command just fail

Comment: @cookiedough Separate posts for separate solutions is fine. This way people can vote for the solutions independently.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kubernetes import client, watch

def wait_for_job(self):
    logger.info("Waiting for job to complete...")
    w = watch.Watch()
    # timeout_seconds=0 -> will run watch for infinite time, but doesn't raise exception when wait is over
    # _request_timeout=timeout -> it is max timeout for request
    for event in w.stream(
        client.BatchV1Api().list_namespaced_job,
        namespace=self.namespace,
        label_selector=f"job-name={self.job_name}",
        timeout_seconds=0,
        _request_timeout=self.active_deadline_seconds
    ):
        o = event["object"]

        print(o.metadata.name)
        if o.status.succeeded:
            w.stop()
            return

        if not o.status.active and o.status.failed:
            w.stop()
            raise Exception("Job Failed")
```